# Logistic or Poisson Regression for Mortality Modelling?

Tags: logistic, poisson-regression, mortality

I am attempting to model the probability of death while controlling for a number of other variables.  I began to do this with standard logistic regression, but I've come across a number of articles that use Poisson regression to model mortality rates.  My independent variable is death (0/1).  Is Poisson regression preferred to Logistic Regression when modelling something like death or vice versa?  If so why?

Comment: It depends on the data setup and research question. Since your interest is in the probability of death and your independent variable is 0/1, logistic regression is suitable here. The other articles might have been counting the incidents of death. Then their response variable would be count data.

Answer (score 4):

Partially answered in comments:

It depends on the data setup and research question. Since your interest is in the probability of death and your independent variable is 0/1, logistic regression is suitable here. The other articles might have been counting the incidents of death. Then their response variable would be count data. – Greenparker

Comment: I'd add another factoid: the articles that use Poisson are probably counting the number of deaths where the observation is something like a hospital, a county, or some other group (and they would have standardized the exposure, e.g. deaths per 1,000 discharges or person-years). If the original poster has individuals as the unit of observation, then Poisson can't be appropriate (unless we're in some world where you can die multiple times).

Answer (score 2):

Another point is that researchers sometimes use Poisson regression with an offset of log(population size) even when modelling "rate" or probability (and not total number). For outcomes *with low probabilities*, the results will be very similar (the link functions [logit and log], as well as the variance functions [$np(1-p)$ and $\mu$], are very similar when the probability is close to 0).

Logistic regression still makes more sense as a model of the system (Poisson regression in principle would allow for rates > 1). I don't honestly know whether Poisson regression is preferred in some fields because it has (or used to have) computational advantages, or because it *might* have slightly better finite-sample properties (the latter is complete speculation).